# Error: At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting | R Shiny App

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have been getting the following error when I run my Shiny App.

> **At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting**

[Image File for Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVOXn.png)

I went through a few answers that were available regarding this, however none of the options worked, like changing facet_wrap to facet_grid.

The app.R file:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

AorData <- read.csv(file="E:\\DrWheeler\\DataManipulation\\AoristicEstimates.csv",
                    header=TRUE)
AorData$HourF <- hour(hms(AorData$Hour))
AorData$WkDay <- factor(AorData$Week, levels=1:7, labels=c('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'))


server <- function(input, output) {

  act1 <- reactive({
    AorData[,input$Location]
  })

  act2 <- reactive({
    AorData[,input$Crime]
  })

  subdata <- reactive(function(act2,act1){
    subset(AorData, ucr_redString == act2 & RedLoc == act1)
  })

  output$data <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(data= subdata(), aes(x=HourF, y=per_aor, group=WkDay)) + 
      geom_line(size=1.05) +  
      geom_point(shape=21,fill="black",color="white", size=3.5, stroke=1.7) +
      facet_wrap( ~ WkDay)})
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Aoristic Estimate"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Location", "LOCATION", AorData$RedLoc),
      selectInput("Crime", "CRIME", AorData$ucr_redString)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("data")
    )
  )

)

shinyApp(ui=ui, server= server)
```

Link to the data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0yg3n2nfmmvr140/AoristicEstimates.csv?dl=0

The plot works perfectly when I run it independently. But does not work within the app.

[Image of resultant plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uoy0.png)

Can anyone please assist me with this? I have been following tutorials to build this app, hence there is a possibility of me missing a basic step.

Thank you very much!